# Install new AET token via Company Hub

Tags: windows-phone, enterprise, company-hub

We are currently in the process of making a Company Hub App. Now we understand the users will have to install the AET token to be able to install the Company Hub App - that in itself is no problem.

But we have read that the AET token has to be refreshed each year. What we are wondering is;

Is it possible to refresh/install the AET token from the Company Hub App?

I want to spare users the pain of having to install the AET token. Most regular users don't understand why they have to do this in the first place  which prevents them from wanting to install the App.

If we would be able to refresh the AET token automatically that would help a lot?

**Edit**
I don't mind using a method with which the App cannot be allowed in the Market.

Comment: I remember having a similar problem with a website that required refreshing authentication tokens. I ended up making a C# program as scheduled task that would do the process for my users through a web browser control. But I ran that on my server, not through the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here [Frequently asked questions about Windows Phone Company Hub apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/04/21/frequently-asked-questions-about-windows-phone-company-hub-apps.aspx):

> 3. What happens to company hub apps when AET token expires?
>
> Once the AET token expires, company hub apps, signed using the same
>   cert, fails to run on device. AET token is valid for a year. You need
>   to update the AET token on the device before it expires. You can push
>   new AET to device using MDM or for unmanaged scenarios it has to be
>   installed manually via email or IE.

I started search from there, and IMHO, to allow auto install AET tokens automatically will be unsecure, and will ruin the whole idea of AET tokens. So i think it is better to find proper words to describe that AET is required for security reasons, and it is strongly recomended to install it.